# How can I use variables as arguments in my blackSnowEvent function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to pass in the duration variable as an argument to the wait function, or even call the wait function itself in the blackSnowEvent function, I get the "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property ''" Error. I'm not sure what to do. (I call the blackSnowEvent function in another script (PlayerCollision.cs))

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    private static bool snowActivated = false;
    public int duration = 5;

    // This is also a singleton just like AudioManger
   #region Singleton

    private static GameManager instance;

    public static GameManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;    
        }
    }


    void Start()
    {
        AudioManager.Instance.Play(SoundType.BackgroundTheme);
    }

 IEnumerator wait(int arg){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(arg);
    }
   
    public static void blackSnowEvent(ParticleSystem particleSystem, GameObject snowTrigger){
        if(snowActivated == false){
             snowActivated = true;
            snowTrigger.SetActive(false);
            particleSystem.Play();

            StartCoroutine(wait(duration));

            particleSystem.Stop();
           
           snowActivated = false;
        }
 

    } 

    #endregion
   

}
```

Comment: `duration` isn't static, like the function or `snowActivated`. You could make it static or use something like `GameManager.Instance.duration`. Same issue with the `wait` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a non-static method `StartCoroutine(wait(duration))` in a static method `blackSnoEvent()`, which throws an error. You either have to make your `wait()` method static or make `blackSnowEvent()` non-static. If you make `blackSnowEvent()` non-static, you access it from the other script using `GameManager.Instance.blackSnowEvent()`

**Recommended:**
Make all our fields and methods in your script non-static. If you want to call a method in this script, you access it using `GameManager.Instance.SomeMethod()` given `SomeMethod()` is a public method.